# Cas with JDBC error Error creating bean with name 'handlerMappingC'

Tags: java, cas

I got error when I configured CAS with JDBC.
And here is where I try to setup the database connection in WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml:

```
<bean class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler">
                    <property name="tableUsers">
                        <value>users</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="fieldUser">
                        <value>username</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="fieldPassword">
                        <value>password</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="passwordEncoder">
                        <bean
                            class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.DefaultPasswordEncoder">
                            <constructor-arg value="MD5" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                </bean>

<bean id="datasource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>root</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value></value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

addition I added into POM.xml file

```html
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
   <artifactId>cas-server-support-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>${cas.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.22-bin</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

when build got error

```
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'centralAuthenticationService' while setting bean property 'centralAuthenticationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralAuthenticationService' defined in file [E:\Projects\Eload4\cas-3.5.3\cas-3.5.3\cas-server-webapp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\spring-configuration\applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationManager' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler#14692d2' of type [org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler] while setting bean property 'authenticationHandlers' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler#14692d2' defined in URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.jasig.cas.WiringTests.setUp(WiringTests.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message say `No bean named 'dataSource' is defined` you have not defined a bean named `'dataSource'`. Your bean has a lower `s`.

so you have to change `<bean id="datasource"` to `<bean id="dataSource"`

Comment: Thank you, because I copied this code on the internet so i don't check, thanks again